# How do I create my .run file to install Qt 5.9.0 on 32-bit debian?

Tags: qt, debian, qt5.9

As per my information, Binaries (or offline/online installers) for installing Qt (>= 5.6) on 32-bit linux are not provided. For example, If I want to use Qt 5.9.0 on 32-bit linux (debian, specifically), the only option is to download Qt source and build it. I have successfully built Qt 5.9.0 on my 32-bit linux machine. But I have to do this on all my development PC's. Instead if I can build it once and create an installer somehow, that will save a lot of time. Is there a way to create offline installer (e.g. *.run files) for installing Qt 5.9.0 on 32-bit Linux (e.g. debian)?

Comment: In the Debian buster or sid repositories (https://packages.debian.org/buster/qt5-default) the Qt is at 5.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Velkan, Qt is available on 32 bit Debian from the official repos.

But, indeed, there is no 32-bit Linux installer from the Qt project.

Regarding copying a Qt install from a Debian PC to another, you do not need to create an installer. Just copy/tar/zip the directory in which Qt is installed. The only requirement is that you must keep the installation in the same absolute path as the Qt Core library has the path hardcoded in it and it is use for plugin detection.

*NB1: It is possible to patch Qt Core library to change the hardcoded path and even make it relative. It is not officially documented but you can take a look in the sources of tools like `windeployqt` or the online installer*

*NB2: Do not use Qt 5.9.0, prefer 5.9.2. Both are forward and backward binary compatible, but the latter received bug fixes.*